# Strategy alert to output 'open' or 'close'

Tags: pine-script

I have a pine script strategy, which does simple buy/sell orders using:

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = cond1)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when = cond2)
strategy.close("Long", when = cond3)
strategy.exit(id="TrailStop", stop=shortStopPrice)
```

Now I am setting up a Tradingview alert which needs to output specific information.

I can output buy or sell using `{{strategy.order.action}}`, but I also need to output the words **close** or **open**. Do you know how I can get this value in the alert message box? Does it exist in some sort of standard variable of strategy? Or can I assign it in the script and call it in the alert box?

Update: based on the answer of bjorn-mistiaen, I added a comment. It works fine for .entry and .exit, but not for .close:

```
strategy.close(id = "Long", when = cond3, comment="test")
```

returns:

[image]

Hoovering the function shows me that comment is a valid argument though. I don't really understand the debug error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use `{{strategy.order.comment}}`

> This returns the comment of the executed order (the string used in the
> comment parameter in one of the function calls generating orders:
> strategy.entry, strategy.exit or strategy.order). If no comment is
> specified, then the value of strategy.order.id will be used.

Source: [How to use a variable value in alert](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/pK7jCRHN/?solution=43000531021)

That `comment` is a parameter in [strategy.entry()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dentry) which you could give the strings `open` and `close`.

```
strategy.entry(id, long, qty, limit, stop, oca_name, oca_type, comment, when, alert_message)
```

Comment: That works for strategy entry, but not for the exit() and close(). "Cannot call strategy.close; with arguments

Comment: Update: it works with exit(), but I need it to work with close(). I'll update the question with a screenshot of the error message I get when adding the comment.

Comment: Oh, got it, was using an old pine version: //@version=4  solved it. Thanks!